# Why is the latent loss in VAEs is set to the KL divergence?

Tags: machine-learning, autoencoders, generative-models

The KL Divergence is surely not the wrong way to go, but I wonder if there are any VAEs which use something like the Wasserstein Distance or even an l2 loss on the `mean` and `std` towards `0` and `1` respectively.

Comment: [wasserstein vae](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.01558)

Comment: That looks great, I was hoping for a bit more discussion about the meaning of the different losses, but that paper is a great place to start. Thank you :)